# Negative lookahead in regex which matches everything accept a specific character

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am having problems defining a regular expression with a negative lookahead in Java.

Given the following string:

`Today [#[#item#] was|the items were#] shipped so [#it is|they are#] gone.`

I am trying to convert this string to one of the following forms based upon some value (yes it is a way to differentiate between singular and plural form):

`Today [#item#] was shipped so it is gone.` or `Today the items were shipped so they are gone`.

I am trying to use a regex in Java to match this pattern and implement this conversion:

```
public String convert(String text, boolean isSingular) {
    Pattern spPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[#.*?\\|.*?#\\]");
    Matcher matcher = spPattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int start = matcher.start()+2;
        int end = matcher.end()-2;
        int indexOfPipe = text.indexOf("|", start);
        String replacement = (isSingular) ? text.substring(start, indexOfPipe) : text.substring(indexOfPipe+1, end);
        text = matcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
        matcher = spPattern.matcher(text);
     }
}
```

For the singular form: after the first iteration of the `while`-loop `text` is `Today [#item#] was shipped so [#it is|they are#] gone.`, which is ok. However in the second iteration the `Matcher` matches the group `[#item#] was shipped so [#it is|they are#]` while it should be `[#it is|they are#]`. I am pretty sure I need some kind of negative lookahead.

I already tried the following pattern but it did not seem to do anything:

`(\\[#.*?\\|.*?#\\])(?!\\[#[^\\|]*?#\\])` ("try to match everything between [# and #] accept those cases which do not contain a | between those tags")

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you aware that [java.text.MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) already provides this functionality?

Comment: @VGR : For this specific example it should work, yes. However there are some other demands on the system I am implementing which make using [java.text.MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

The issue you're experiencing is because your first replacement is generating `Today [#item#] was shipped so [#it is|they are#] gone.` and your regex is matching `[#item#] was shipped so [#it is|they are#]`. Your regex then replaces this string incorrectly.

The *true* way to solving this would be to create a parser, but regex can be used if the function runs the regex in a *recursive way* (which it *kind of* does thanks to the `while` loop); so this answer also works on something like `[#[#a|b#]|b#]`, but note that any further nesting will fail (if it's nested on the singular side).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Gszthl/1)

```
\[#((?:\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)\|((?:\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)#]
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/0nBHFb)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "Today [#[#item#] was|the items were#] shipped so [#it is|they are#] gone.";
        System.out.println(convert(s, true));
        System.out.println(convert(s, false));
    }

    public static String convert(String text, boolean isSingular) {
        Pattern spPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[#((?:\\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)\\|((?:\\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)#]");
        Matcher matcher = spPattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = isSingular ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2);
            text = matcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
            matcher = spPattern.matcher(text);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `\[#` Matches `[#` literally
- `((?:\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?` Match either of following any number of times, but as few as possible
  - `\[#.*?#]` Match the following

    - `\[#` Matches `[#` literally
    - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
    - `#]` Match this literally
  - `(?!#])[^|]` Match the following

    - `(?!#])` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match `#]` literally
    - `[^|]` Match anything except `|`
- `\|` Match `|` literally
- `((?:\[#.*?#]|(?!#])[^|])*?)` Capture the following into capture group 2

  - See explanation under capture group 1 (this is identical to capture group 1)
- `#]` Matches this literally

Comment: +1 on the parser comment. I did not think of that (the last time I tinkered with parsers is about 15 years ago in university) but might give it a try if I have some time left. In the mean time your regex works perfectly for my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code showing a way this could be done.
Obviously I don't know Java.

`regex_main = "(?s)(.*?)((?=\\[\\#)(?:(?=.*?\\[\\#(?!.*?\\3)(.*\\#\\](?!.*\\4).*))(?=.*?\\#\\](?!.*?\\4)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\\3)(?:(?!\\[\\#).)*)(?=\\4)|(.+)"`

`regex_brack_contents = "(?s)^\\[\\#(.*)\\#\\]$"`

```
sTemplate = "Today [#[#item#] was|the items were#] shipped so [#it is|they are#] gone."
sOut[5] = ""
nPermutations = 0
Matcher _M = regex_main.matcher( sTemplate );

while ( _M.find() ) {
    if ( _M.group(1) ) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
            sOut[i] += _M.group(1)
        Matcher _m = regex_brack_contents.matcher( _M.group(2) )
        if ( _m.find() ) {
            aray = _m.group(1).split("|");
            for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(aray), i < 5; i++ )
                sOut[i] += aray[i]
            if ( i > nPermutations )
                nPermutations = i
        }
    }
    else { 
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
           sOut[i] += _M.group(5)
    }
    _M = regex_main.matcher( sTemplate );
}
for (i = 0; i < nPermutations; i++ ) 
    print( sOut[i] + "\r\n" )
```